# (Js puro) função que filtre array de maneira que retorne arrays unicos com elementos distintos

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

```
var list =[
[3,4,7,9,4],[3,4,7,9,5],[3,4,7,9,6],[3,4,7,9,7],
[3,4,7,9,8],[3,4,7,9,9],[3,4,8,3,3],[3,4,8,3,4],
[3,4,8,3,5],[3,4,8,3,6],[3,4,8,3,7],[3,4,8,3,8],
[3,4,8,3,9],[3,6,4,6,7],[3,6,4,6,8],[3,6,4,6,9],
[3,6,4,7,3],[3,6,4,7,4],[3,6,4,7,5],[3,6,4,7,6],
[3,6,4,7,7],[3,6,4,7,8],[3,6,4,7,9],[3,6,4,8,3],
[3,6,4,8,4],[3,6,4,8,5],[3,6,4,8,6],[3,6,4,8,7],
[6,7,8,8,7],[6,7,8,8,8],[6,7,8,8,9],[6,7,8,9,3],
[6,7,8,9,4],[6,7,8,9,5],[6,7,8,9,6],[6,7,8,9,7],
[6,7,8,9,8],[6,7,8,9,9],[6,7,9,3,3],[6,7,9,3,4],
[6,7,9,3,5],[6,7,9,3,6],[6,7,9,3,7],[6,7,9,3,8],
[6,7,9,4,5],[6,7,9,4,6],[6,7,9,4,7],[6,7,9,4,8],
[6,7,9,4,9],[6,7,9,5,3],[6,7,9,5,4],[6,7,9,5,5],
[6,7,9,5,6],[6,7,9,5,7],[6,7,9,5,8],[6,7,9,5,9],
]
```

Ex: os arrays abaixo todos seriam eliminados pois possuem elementos repetidos dentro

```
[3,4,7,9,4]
[3,6,4,7,7]
[6,7,9,4,9]
[6,7,9,5,6]
```

Nos casos abaixo os elementos são distintos porem eles se repetem com posicionamento diferente em um outro array, nesse caso um seria eliminado e outro permaneceria se tornando unico dentro do array principal

```
[3,6,4,7,9]
[3,4,7,9,6]

[3,6,4,8,7]
[3,6,4,7,8]
```

Comment: Já ouvi falar em Expressões Regulares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve o seu problema:

```js
var list =[
[3,4,7,9,4],[3,4,7,9,5],[3,4,7,9,6],[3,4,7,9,7],
[3,4,7,9,8],[3,4,7,9,9],[3,4,8,3,3],[3,4,8,3,4],
[3,4,8,3,5],[3,4,8,3,6],[3,4,8,3,7],[3,4,8,3,8],
[3,4,8,3,9],[3,6,4,6,7],[3,6,4,6,8],[3,6,4,6,9],
[3,6,4,7,3],[3,6,4,7,4],[3,6,4,7,5],[3,6,4,7,6],
[3,6,4,7,7],[3,6,4,7,8],[3,6,4,7,9],[3,6,4,8,3],
[3,6,4,8,4],[3,6,4,8,5],[3,6,4,8,6],[3,6,4,8,7],
[6,7,8,8,7],[6,7,8,8,8],[6,7,8,8,9],[6,7,8,9,3],
[6,7,8,9,4],[6,7,8,9,5],[6,7,8,9,6],[6,7,8,9,7],
[6,7,8,9,8],[6,7,8,9,9],[6,7,9,3,3],[6,7,9,3,4],
[6,7,9,3,5],[6,7,9,3,6],[6,7,9,3,7],[6,7,9,3,8],
[6,7,9,4,5],[6,7,9,4,6],[6,7,9,4,7],[6,7,9,4,8],
[6,7,9,4,9],[6,7,9,5,3],[6,7,9,5,4],[6,7,9,5,5],
[6,7,9,5,6],[6,7,9,5,7],[6,7,9,5,8],[6,7,9,5,9],
]

// Eliminando arrays com elementos repetidos
let withoutDuplicates = list.filter(l => (new Set(l)).size === l.length)

// Função diff (traz a diferença entre 2 arrays)
Array.prototype.diff = function (a) {
  return this.filter((i) => a.indexOf(i) === -1)
}

let duplicatedKeys = []

// Percorrendo os arrays restantes
withoutDuplicates.forEach((a, i) => {
  // Fazendo outro loop para percorrer os arrays restantes novamente
  withoutDuplicates.forEach((b, x) => {
    // Checando se os elementos comparados não são o mesmo elemento
    // e checando se a diferença entre eles é igual a 0 (se for significa
    // que eles possuem os mesmo valores, mesmo em posições diferentes)
    if(i !== x && a.diff(b).length === 0) {
        // Verifica se o elemento a e b não foram incluídos no array duplicatedKeys
        if(duplicatedKeys.indexOf(a) === -1 && duplicatedKeys.indexOf(b) === -1) {
            // Armazena o elemento no array duplicatedKeys
            duplicatedKeys.push(a)
        }
    }
  })
})

// Removendo as chaves duplicadas que foram armazenadas no array duplicatedKeys
withoutDuplicates = withoutDuplicates.filter(a => duplicatedKeys.indexOf(a) === -1)

console.log(withoutDuplicates)
```

Quando chegar em casa edito e tento explicar melhor o que foi feito...

Comment: nao está funcionando corretamente,[ 6,7, 9, 5, 8 ] [ 6,7,8,9, 5 ] esse dois por exemplo teria que ficar somente 1 deles

Comment: @LucasMota acho que agora tá funcionando, dá uma olhada

Comment: Ainda não. Ex: esses dois array são iguais [[6,7,8,9,5],  [6,7,9,5,8]], tem que ficar pelo menos um deles para ser único dentro do array principal, aqui nesse site tem uma breve explicação no exemplo 2 onde fala sobre combinações

Comment: @LucasMota Acho que agora sim deu certo, dá uma olhada!

Comment: o site era esse aqui https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/arranjo-ou-combinacao.htm . Agora sim está funcionado perfeitamente, obrigada pela ajuda e pela atenção.

Comment: @LucasMota Editei os comentários, acho que ficará um pouco melhor para entender agora!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lista = [
  [3,4,7,9,4],[3,4,7,9,5],[3,4,7,9,6],[3,4,7,9,7],
  [3,4,7,9,8],[3,4,7,9,9],[3,4,8,3,3],[3,4,8,3,4],
  [3,4,8,3,5],[3,4,8,3,6],[3,4,8,3,7],[3,4,8,3,8],
  [3,4,8,3,9],[3,6,4,6,7],[3,6,4,6,8],[3,6,4,6,9],
  [3,6,4,7,3],[3,6,4,7,4],[3,6,4,7,5],[3,6,4,7,6],
  [3,6,4,7,7],[3,6,4,7,8],[3,6,4,7,9],[3,6,4,8,3],
  [3,6,4,8,4],[3,6,4,8,5],[3,6,4,8,6],[3,6,4,8,7],
  [6,7,8,8,7],[6,7,8,8,8],[6,7,8,8,9],[6,7,8,9,3],
  [6,7,8,9,4],[6,7,8,9,5],[6,7,8,9,6],[6,7,8,9,7],
  [6,7,8,9,8],[6,7,8,9,9],[6,7,9,3,3],[6,7,9,3,4],
  [6,7,9,3,5],[6,7,9,3,6],[6,7,9,3,7],[6,7,9,3,8],
  [6,7,9,4,5],[6,7,9,4,6],[6,7,9,4,7],[6,7,9,4,8],
  [6,7,9,4,9],[6,7,9,5,3],[6,7,9,5,4],[6,7,9,5,5],
  [6,7,9,5,6],[6,7,9,5,7],[6,7,9,5,8],[6,7,9,5,9],
]

// 1º Passo - Remover os arrays com itens repetidos.
lista = lista.filter(function (sublista) {
  return sublista.every(function (item, indice) {
    return sublista.indexOf(item) == indice
  })
})

// 2º Passo - não é possivel comparar dois Objetos por valor no JavaScript.
// desta forma, [1, 2, 3] != [1, 2, 3]. porém como se trata de um array de numeros,
// é possivel converter o mesmo para uma string de base64 com a função btoa
// para que que a string base64 para arrays com os mesmos numeros seja igual,
// devemos ordenar os arrays com a função sort, antes de obter a string base64.
// por exemplo, [3, 4, 5, 7, 9] será convertido para "Myw0LDUsNiw4"
var indices = {}
var binarios = lista.map(function (sublista, indice) {
  return { indice: indice, binary: btoa(sublista.sort()) } 
})

// 3º Passo - obtendo o indice da primeira ocorrencia de cada array,
// assim como a quantidade de ocorrencias de arrays com os mesmo elementos.
binarios.forEach(function (item, indice) {
  if (indices[item.binary]) {
    indices[item.binary].total++
  } else {
    indices[item.binary] = { indice: indice, total: 1 }
  }
})

// 4º Passo - Filtrar os arrays, para exibir apenas os arrays cujo a conjunto numerico é unico.
lista = Object.values(indices).filter(function (item) {
  return item.total == 1
}).map(function (item) {
  return lista[item.indice]
})

console.log(lista)
```

Comment: Não está funcionando corretamente.  Amostra : o array  [6,7,9,3,5] não foi incluído.

Answer (score 0):

Ao fazer o teste de mesa, resulta nas seguintes arrays:

```
[3,4,7,9,5]
[3,4,7,9,8]
[3,6,4,7,5]
[3,6,4,8,5]
[3,6,4,8,7]
[6,7,9,3,4]
[6,7,9,3,8]
[6,7,9,4,8]
[6,7,9,5,3]
[6,7,9,5,4]
[6,7,9,5,8]
```

O código abaixo filtra da forma que deseja, substituindo a array original `list` com os elementos filtrados:

```js
var list =[
[3,4,7,9,4],[3,4,7,9,5],[3,4,7,9,6],[3,4,7,9,7],
[3,4,7,9,8],[3,4,7,9,9],[3,4,8,3,3],[3,4,8,3,4],
[3,4,8,3,5],[3,4,8,3,6],[3,4,8,3,7],[3,4,8,3,8],
[3,4,8,3,9],[3,6,4,6,7],[3,6,4,6,8],[3,6,4,6,9],
[3,6,4,7,3],[3,6,4,7,4],[3,6,4,7,5],[3,6,4,7,6],
[3,6,4,7,7],[3,6,4,7,8],[3,6,4,7,9],[3,6,4,8,3],
[3,6,4,8,4],[3,6,4,8,5],[3,6,4,8,6],[3,6,4,8,7],
[6,7,8,8,7],[6,7,8,8,8],[6,7,8,8,9],[6,7,8,9,3],
[6,7,8,9,4],[6,7,8,9,5],[6,7,8,9,6],[6,7,8,9,7],
[6,7,8,9,8],[6,7,8,9,9],[6,7,9,3,3],[6,7,9,3,4],
[6,7,9,3,5],[6,7,9,3,6],[6,7,9,3,7],[6,7,9,3,8],
[6,7,9,4,5],[6,7,9,4,6],[6,7,9,4,7],[6,7,9,4,8],
[6,7,9,4,9],[6,7,9,5,3],[6,7,9,5,4],[6,7,9,5,5],
[6,7,9,5,6],[6,7,9,5,7],[6,7,9,5,8],[6,7,9,5,9],
];

var list2 = list.map(function(v){ return v.join('') });

for(var item in list2){
   list2[item] = list2[item].split('').sort().join('')+" "+item;
}

for(var item in list2){
   var m = list2[item].match(/^\d+/)[0];
   for(var x=0; x<m.length; x++){
      var r = m.match( new RegExp(m[x], 'g') ).length;
      if(r > 1){
         list2[item] = list2[item].replace(m+' ','');
         break;
      }
   }
}

var list2_str = list2.join(); // converto para string

for(var item of list2){
   var padrao = item.match(/^\d+\s/);
   var m = list2_str.match( new RegExp(padrao, 'g') );
   if(m){
      for(var x=1; x<m.length; x++){
         list2_str = list2_str.replace(m[x], '');
      }
   }
}

list2_str = list2_str.split(','); // converto para array

list2_str.filter(function(v){
   if(v.length < 7) list[v] = null;
});

list = list.filter(function(v){ return v; });

// daqui pra baixo apenas para mostrar na div
var div = document.querySelector("#resultado");

for(var item in list){
    div.innerHTML += item+": ["+list[item]+"]<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: esse também está funcionando! muito obrigado pela ajuda